# React useReducer and context: how to provide state selectors?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I was never explicitly clear in the original question, but I'm trying to do all of this *without* Redux, which means no useSelector();

It's an exercise in using just native React to implement selectors.

---

I'm trying to build a Redux-like arrangement, using hooks, and I'm [borrowing heavily from this guy](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/how-to-use-react-context-effectively)

So, we have a Store:

```
const CarStore = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(
    carReducer,
    [
      {
        type: 'fast',
        mpg: 'bad',
      },
    ],
  );

  return (
    <CarStateContext.Provider value={selectors}>
      <CarDispatchContext.Provider value={dispatch}>
        {children}
      </CarDispatchContext.Provider>
    </CarStateContext.Provider>
  );
};
export const CarStateContext = createContext();
export const CarDispatchContext = createContext();
```

Now, `dispatch` automatically has access to `state` via `carReducer`, which is very nice. Instant Redux!

Well, half a Redux, anyway. I'm still missing selectors, and that's my question. Given the above context(s), how could I best build out, for example, a selector like `getCarType()` that would return just 'fast' to a component?

One vague idea would be something like this:

```
const CarStore = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(
    carReducer,
    [
      {
        type: 'fast',
        mpg: 'bad',
      },
    ],
  );

  // selectors, kind of. 
  const selectors = {
    getType: () => { return state.type; },
    getMpg: () => { return state.mpg; },
  };

  return (
    <CarStateContext.Provider value={selectors}> // <- don't return state, return selectors
      <CarDispatchContext.Provider value={dispatch}>
        {children}
      </CarDispatchContext.Provider>
    </CarStateContext.Provider>
  );
};
export const CarStateContext = createContext();
export const CarDispatchContext = createContext();
```

This does work, I guess, but there's probably a better solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best and generic solution here is to provide a simple API called `useSelector` as provided by redux which takes a callback and calls it with the current state and returns the result.

```
const CarStore = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(
    carReducer,
    [
      {
        type: 'fast',
        mpg: 'bad',
      },
    ],
  );


  const useSelector = (callback) => {
    return callback(state)
  };

  return (
    <CarStateContext.Provider value={{useSelector}}> // <- don't return state, return selectors
      <CarDispatchContext.Provider value={dispatch}>
        {children}
      </CarDispatchContext.Provider>
    </CarStateContext.Provider>
  );
};
export const CarStateContext = createContext();
export const CarDispatchContext = createContext();
```

Once you do that you can use it an any component like

```
const Comp = () => {
   const {useSelector} = useContext(CarStateContext);
   const type = useSelector((state) => { return state.type; })
   const mpg = useSelector((state) => { return state.mpg; })

}
```

**EDIT- Approach 2:** In the above scenario you need to make use of `useContext` separately along with `useSelector` To avoid it you can implement useSelector as a hook too. Also you don't need two separete context for dispatch and state, you can make use of just one

```
const CarStore = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(
    carReducer,
    [
      {
        type: 'fast',
        mpg: 'bad',
      },
    ],
  );


  const getValue = (callback) => {
    return callback(state)
  };

  return (
    <CarStateContext.Provider value={{getValue, dispatch}}> // <- don't return state, return selectors
        {children}
    </CarStateContext.Provider>
  );
};
export const CarStateContext = createContext();

export const useSelector = (callback) => {
   const {getValue} = useContext(CarStateContext);
   return getValue(callback)
}
// Similarly dispatch can be provided like below
export const useDispatch = () => {
   const {dispatch} = useContext(CarStateContext);
   return dispatch
}
```

---

and use it in your component like

```
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'path/to/useSelector'
const Comp = () => {
   const type = useSelector((state) => { return state.type; })
   const mpg = useSelector((state) => { return state.mpg; })
   const dispatch = useDispatch();
}
```

Comment: This is a really great and thorough answer. Thanks. However, and this was clear in my head as I wrote the question, but I now realize never explicitly stated in what I wrote, I'm trying to do all of this _without_ redux.

I'm going to leave the question open for a while, then accept your answer if there are no other suggestions, because I suspect it is the generally adopted solution.

Comment: @crowhill this answer does _not_ use redux. It just mimics the redux pattern.

Comment: If I understand correctly, this solution will cause all child components to re-render on every state change, right?

Comment: That's right, @eli. It's just a flaw of the default react contexts :(

Comment: No way to prevent rendering the components which use the state of the Context. I tried all above and all work well; but all solution produce re-rendering components whenever you change a pice of the state which the component uses another part of the state.